# ¿Cómo convertir texto image a voz con jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Indagando en la web encontré dos opciones

- ResponsiveVoiceJS
- PHP y vozME

Un ejemplo sencillo de **ResponsiveVoiceJS**

```js
$("a.say").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $("input[name=text]").val();
  responsiveVoice.speak(text,"Spanish Female");
  text=encodeURIComponent(text);
  var url="http://"
})
```

```html
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>

 <input type="text" name="text">
  <a href="#" class="say">Escuchar Texto!</a>
  <audio src="" hidden class=speech></audio>
```

La más relevante es **ResponsiveVoiceJS** se ve algo simple y sencillo.

> El único problema es que lee todo el texto, lo ideal es deletrear el texto para una imagen captcha.

Esta es la session del captcha donde obtengo el valor de los caracteres.

```
$_SESSION['secure'] = '';
```

**captcha.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(120,46); 
$white = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,rand(78,181),rand(163,35),rand(36,7));
imagefill($image,0,0,$white);

imagerectangle($image,1,1,99,39 ,$white);
$source = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$first = $source[mt_rand(0,61)];
$second = $source[mt_rand(0,61)];
$third = $source[mt_rand(0,61)];
$fourth = $source[mt_rand(0,61)];
$_SESSION['secure'] = $first.$second.$third.$fourth;
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),10,30,$black,"Quixley.ttf",$first);
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),30,30,$black,"AntykwaBold.ttf",$second);
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),50,30,$black,"Ding-DongDaddyO.ttf",$third);
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),70,30,$black,"Duality.ttf",$fourth);
header("content-type:image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

la validación del **captcha**

```
  <div id="captcha">
    <img src="captcha.php" name="secure" id="imgsecure"/>
    <input name="secure" type="text" placeholder="Por favor, ingrese el texto que figura la imagen.">
    <div class="update"><a href="javascript:reloadCaptcha();">Actualizar código captcha</a></div>
  </div>
```

Ahora mi pregunta?

Como reproduzco el texto que genera la imagen captcha a voz tomando en cuenta los detalles mencionados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira este [link](https://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/creating-audio-files/)... un captcha con voz en PHP/JS... a veces no hay que reinventar la rueda una y otra vez ;)

Comment: No conozco estos plugins...pero supongo que tienes que formar el audio en el lado del servidor para luego descargarlo....pero quizás puedas aprender como lo hacen ellos... mirando su código ;) ...

Answer (score 1):

No creo que esto es lo más ideal o seguro para el sistema del captcha, ya que tendrías que pasar el contenido del captcha, ósea la palabra de la imagen al `ResponsiveVoiceJS` y se conoce que una vez en el lado del cliente... *la palabra estará opuesto a usuarios sospechosos*...

Pero te dejo como se podría *deletrear* el texto:

```js
$("a.say").on('click', function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var text = $("input[name=text]").prop('value');
  text = text.split('');
  
  $.each(text, function(i, item) {        
    responsiveVoice.speak(item, "Spanish Female");
  });  
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>

<!-- Ejemplo para pasar el valor del $_SESSION['secure'] -->

<!-- <input type="hidden" name="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['secure']; ?>"> -->


<input type="hidden" name="text" value="globo">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lFwO.png">
<a href="#" class="say">Escuchar Texto Imágen!</a>
<audio src="" hidden class=speech></audio>
```

Comment: Solo se escucha la última letra.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo - deberías explicar en cual entorno no te funciona... porque funciona en chrome, ff y safari

Comment: Hola @aldanux Ya se que me habías dicho que por motivos de seguridad no es recomendable pero cómo adaptaría este código al código captcha para reproducir la imagen a voz?

Answer (score 0):

También puedes considerar usar la [`API SpeechSynthesisUtterance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance) ([`Edge+`](http://caniuse.com/#search=SpeechSynthesisUtterance)),

Así por ejemplo:

```js
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  var voice = document.getElementById('voice');
  var speek = document.getElementById('speek');
  var spell = document.getElementById('spell');
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

  var voices;
  speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    voices.forEach(function (v, idx) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerText = v.name;
      opt.value = idx;
      voice.appendChild(opt);
    });
  };

  speek.addEventListener('click', function(){
    msg.text = text.value;
    msg.voice = voices[voice.value];
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
  });

  // Deletrear
  spell.addEventListener('click', function(){
    msg.text = text.value.split('').join('-');
    msg.voice = voices[voice.value];
    msg.rate = .2; // Velocidad de voz
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value="Hola" /><select id="voice"></select><button id="speek">Hablar</button><button id="spell">Deletrar</button>
```

Comment: Interesante la API a pesar de estar aprueba funciona perfectamente. Me habían recomendado que por medidas de seguridad nos era recomendable utilizarla para reproducir la imagen del captcha a voz. Pero cómo adaptaría este código al código captcha para reproducir la imagen a voz?

Comment: @J.Doe, no lo tomes a mal, pero básicamente nos estas pidiendo que lo hagamos por vos. Intenta hacer algunas pruebas primero, y pública tu código hasta donde llegues planteando los problemas que te surjan.

Answer (score 0):

Separa las letras con espacios, así deletreará:

```js
$("a.say").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $("input[name=text]").val();
      text = text.split('').join('  ')
  responsiveVoice.speak(text,"Spanish Female");
  text=encodeURIComponent(text);
  var url="http://"
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>

 <input type="text" name="text">
  <a href="#" class="say">Escuchar Texto!</a>
  <audio src="" hidden class=speech></audio>
```

Para controlar el tiempo en que se dicen las letras, puedes usar promises:

```js
$("a.say").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $("input[name=text]").val();
  deletrea(text)
})

function deletrea(palabra){
  palabra.split('').reduce(function(promise, letra){
    console.log(letra);
    return promise.then(function(){
      responsiveVoice.speak(letra,"Spanish Female");
      return esperar(1500);
    })
  }, Promise.resolve())
}

function esperar(ms){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>

 <input type="text" name="text">
  <a href="#" class="say">Escuchar Texto!</a>
  <audio src="" hidden class=speech></audio>
```